# How to assert data in a JSON array with Python

Tags: python, json, api, automation

I am trying to automate some API endpoints, but the JSON response is an array of data. How can I assert a specific user with all his data inside that JSON array?

I am trying with:

```
assert  {
            "user": "test1",
            "userName": "John Berner",
            "userid": "1"
        } in response.json()
```

The JSON response is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "user": "test1",
            "userName": "John Berner",
            "userid": "1"
        },
        {
            "user": "test2",
            "userName": "Nick Morris",
            "userid": "2"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "pages": 1,
        "per_page": 100,
        "total": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:
You can use loop over the `data` within any to perform this check.

```
contents = json.loads(apiresponse_data)
assert any(i['user'] == 'test1' for i in contents['data'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the fields are in the response are part of your `user_info` you can do what you are thinking of doing -

```
# response = json.loads(api_response_data)
response = {
    "data": [
        {
            "user": "test1",
            "userName": "John Berner",
            "userid": "1"
        },
        {
            "user": "test2",
            "userName": "Nick Morris",
            "userid": "2"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "pages": 1,
        "per_page": 100,
        "total": 2
    }
}

user_info = {
    "user": "test1",
    "userName": "John Berner",
    "userid": "1"
}

assert user_info in response['data']
```

Above doesn't raise `AssertionError` because the `user_info` is there in the `response['data']`

You can also use following if you have decoded the json response already -

```
assert {
    "user": "test1",
    "userName": "John Berner",
    "userid": "1"
} in response['data']
```